# How to change build settings using pipeline deployment in heroku

Tags: java, node.js, heroku, pipeline

I'm using pipeline deployment method on heroku for java, that is great an easy. Now, I introduced NODEJS and GRUNT. In grunt.js file I wrote a piece of code to use configuration depending on system variables, so when build is done, depending on those heroku system variables, code is being modified a bit (in this case JS code)
It works fine on my first app on pipeline, but when I promote to next stage, as code is not being build, all the modifications remains the same.

How can I make this modifications in JS code if build is not done?
Many thanks!